# Excluding a value within a range of values defined by "between" in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if it is possible to exclude a value inside a range defined by "between".

Here is an example:

```
 ...
 WHEN left(name,2) between 'AA' and 'AZ' then 'HALLO'
 ...
```

I want to exclude from this range, for example, the value 'AM'
Is there a short way to obtain this or I need to split the range into two different ones as follow?

```
 ...
 WHEN left(name,2) between 'AA' and 'AL' then 'HALLO'
 WHEN left(name,2) between 'AN' and 'AZ' then 'HALLO'
 ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHEN left(name,2) between 'AA' and 'AZ' AND NOT left(name,2) = 'AM' then 'HALLO'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put your more restrictive case first:

```
CASE 
WHEN left(name,2) == 'AM' then 'wohoo'
WHEN left(name,2) between 'AA' and 'AZ' then 'HALLO'
END
```

If it matches 'AM' then since that case is first in the statement, its action will be taken, even though the second case also matches 'AM'.

Answer (score 1):

You it is possible:

```
...
WHEN (left(name,2) between 'AA' and 'AZ') AND (left(name,2) <> 'AM') 
     then 'HALLO'
...
```